# Draw boxes on image through the coordinated recieved from AI model in React JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

How to draw a boxes on the image after getting the coordinates from AI model in react js?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use canvas rect() method as per description https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp